# Difference between dates in many columns in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID Date1               Date2               Date3
A  2016-04-25 09:15:29 2016-04-25 14:01:19 2016-04-26 13:28:19
B  2016-04-25 09:15:29 2016-04-25 14:01:19 2016-04-26 13:28:19
```

I want the difference in hours between each date combination (ideally only going forward in time i.e. no negative differences). I know how to do this manually ([calculating number of days between 2 columns of dates in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666172/calculating-number-of-days-between-2-columns-of-dates-in-data-frame)):

```
df$Date2_Date1 <- difftime(df$Date2,df$Date1, units = c("hours"))
```

However, my real data frame is much bigger and this would be very tedious (but possible). I have read this ([Calculate pairwise-difference between each pair of columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187402/calculate-pairwise-difference-between-each-pair-of-columns-in-dataframe)) and this ([R: Compare all the columns pairwise in matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933788/r-compare-all-the-columns-pairwise-in-matrix)) which lead me to try this:

```
nm1 <- outer(colnames(df), colnames(df), paste, sep="_")
indx1 <-  which(lower.tri(nm1, diag=TRUE))
df2 <- outer(1:ncol(df), 1:ncol(df), 
             function(x,y) df[,x]-df[,y])
```

Which I think is getting me close but my ideal output is this:

```
ID Date2_Date1 Date3_Date1 Date3_Date2
A  x hours     y hour      ...
B  ..
```

Are there any nice solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, based on `combn()` and `apply()`:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID=c('A','B'),
    Date1=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-25 09:15:29','2016-04-25 09:15:29')),
    Date2=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-25 14:01:19','2016-04-25 14:01:19')),
    Date3=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-26 13:28:19','2016-04-26 13:28:19')),
    stringsAsFactors=F
);
```

---

```
cmb <- combn(seq_len(ncol(df)-1L)+1L,2L);
res <- abs(apply(cmb,2L,function(x) difftime(df[[x[1L]]],df[[x[2L]]],units='hours')));
colnames(res) <- apply(cmb,2L,function(x,cns) paste0(cns[x[1L]],'_',cns[x[2L]]),names(df));
res;
##      Date1_Date2 Date1_Date3 Date2_Date3
## [1,]    4.763889    28.21389       23.45
## [2,]    4.763889    28.21389       23.45
```

Comment: Thank you that works. I'm having a few problems apply to my real data. I think because I have more ID columns to group by. Does "-1L" in the cmb remove the ID col?

Comment: Yes, the `-1L` removes the `ID` column since it must not participate in the combinations computation. Regarding grouping, I assumed you did not need to group by `ID` for this task because your example code does not group by `ID` (referring to your manual solution `df$Date2_Date1 <- difftime(df$Date2,df$Date1, units = c("hours"))`).

Comment: Yes you are right I don't need to group by anything. I just need to adapt the code to be "-2L". My fault I should have posted exactly by format type.

Comment: Almost. I just get this error: Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time1) : 'origin' must be supplied, when I run "res". But I think that must be a date conversion issue. I'm sure I'll find in on SO.