# Time difference between dates of adjacent columns in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to adapt the answer to my previous question ([Difference between dates in many columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319796/difference-between-dates-in-many-columns-in-r/37320086?noredirect=1#comment62160304_37320086)). I've realised I only want the time difference between a given column, and the column immediately to it's left. Example for clarification:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group=c("A","B"),
  ID=c(1,2),
  Date1=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-25 09:15:29','2016-04-25 09:15:29')),
  Date2=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-25 14:01:19','2016-04-25 14:01:19')),
  Date3=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-26 13:28:19','2016-04-26 13:28:19')),
  stringsAsFactors=F
)
```

My desired output is Date2-Date1 and Date3-Date2. And this of course would extend for many columns i.e. Date4-Date3 etc. But I do not need Date3-Date1. To clarify, how can I automate this for many columns

```
df$Date2_Date1 <- difftime(df$Date2,df$Date1, units = c("hours"))
df$Date3_Date2 <- difftime(df$Date3,df$Date2, units = c("hours"))
```

Thanks to @bgoldst for the original answer. I think I just need to adapt cmb below to have the correct sequence:

```
cmb <- combn(seq_len(ncol(df)-1L)+1L,2L);
res <- abs(apply(cmb,2L,function(x) difftime(df[[x[1L]]],df[[x[2L]]],units='hours')));
colnames(res) <- apply(cmb,2L,function(x,cns) paste0(cns[x[1L]],'_',cns[x[2L]]),names(df))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, this should to the trick:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group=c("A","B"),
  ID=c(1,2),
  Date1=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-25 09:15:29','2016-04-25 09:15:29')),
  Date2=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-25 14:01:19','2016-04-25 14:01:19')),
  Date3=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-26 13:28:19','2016-04-26 13:28:19')),
  stringsAsFactors=F
)
mapply(difftime, df[, 4:5], df[, 3:4], units = "hours")
```

> >     Date2 Date3
>   > [1,] 4.763889 23.45
>   > [2,] 4.763889 23.45

In my call `mapply` applies function `difftime` to the two arrays provided, so it starts with `df[, 4] - df[, 3]`, then `df[, 5] - df[, 4]`. You of course have to change this with the column numbers for your dates, and make sure they are ordered in the right way.

Good luck!

Comment: You can find the appropriate column with `which` and then calculate adjacent column by simply adding/subtracting up/down the data.frame.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, this worked very nicely. Roman, would you mind clarifying with a little bit of example code so I can try.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Non-Standard Evaluation:

1. First you create a character vector with the name of the columns containing the dates. So let' say all the columns starting with 'Date'

   ```
   dates = names(df)[grepl("^Date", names(df))]
   ```
2. We create a list of formulas that dynamically calculate the difference between to adjacent columns:

   ```
   all_operations = lapply(seq_len(length(dates) - 1), function(i){
       as.formula(paste("~difftime(", dates[i + 1], ",", dates[i],", units = c('hours'))"))
   })
   ```

   this will create the formulas:

   ```
   [[1]]:  ~difftime(Date2, Date1, units = c("hours"))
   [[2]]:  ~difftime(Date3, Date2, units = c("hours"))
   ```
3. Then you can use dplyr's NSE mutate_ to apply the dynamic formulas generated above:

   ```
   df %>%
      mutate_(.dots = setNames(all_operations, paste0("Diff", seq_len(length(dates) - 1))))
   ```

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. I wish I could accept two answers. This also worked very nicely! The only reason I accepted Jaspers is because I understood it more which is perhaps not a good reason.